# Selective Service permissions, binding only

Tags: android

Is it possible to restrict access to a `Service` such that a client can only bind to it?  For example, I want clients to access the service's AIDL API, but do not want them to be able to call `startService()` or, more importantly, `stopService()` on the service.

I have tried using the `android:permission` attribute within the `<service>` tag of the manifest.  This works for restricting access to `startService()` and `stopService()` but binding to the Service configured in this way results in:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to restrict access to a Service such that a client can only bind to it?

Not that I am aware of, other than to not do anything in `onStartCommand()` and therefore make sending commands be a no-op.

> For example, I want clients to access the service's AIDL API, but do not want them to be able to call startService() or, more importantly, stopService() on the service.

Sounds like you need two services: one with your public AIDL API, one that serves whatever private role you have going via the command pattern.

Comment: Thank you. I've implemented a second Service to act as the AIDL "gateway" with the original Service permission protected. Works great!